# Angular app running in nginx docker container cannot access images in a volume

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have an angular app that is hosted on my local machine using the docker nginx image.
The Image runs properly and I can access the angular app through the browser with localhost:port, however I have an issue where I the app cannot load images from a volume attached to the container.

I have tried in my component.html:

```
<img mat-card-image src="/data/path/to/img.jpg"  alt="Image">
```

but the image only shows the alt text.

In the console it shows an error:

```
img.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/data/path/to/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I have also tried setting the img src as a relative path from the nginx html folder but that also gave me a similar error message.

How can I make my angular app display an image from a docker volume?

Thanks

Comment: To add: The error in my nginx console shows this/ "webapp    | 2021/02/15 21:36:35 [error] 29#29: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/data/path/to/img.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.21.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /data/path/to/img.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/library""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I just had to mount my volume to the nginx public html folder.